# Getting error while adding FileUpload Webservice

Tags: asp.net, web-services, webforms, image-upload

I want to create a **web service** in
**Asp.Net** `WebService.asmx`
to add image, so I added **fileUpload**

```
 string uploadImage(FileUpload file_upload_control, int order_id)
    {

        string path = Server.MapPath($"/orders_images/");
        string directory = Path.Combine(path, order_id.ToString());
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
        string file = "";
        if (file_upload_control.HasFile)
        {
            file = System.IO.Path.Combine(directory, file_upload_control.FileName);
            file_upload_control.SaveAs(file);
        }
        string file_name = file_upload_control.FileName;
        return file_name;
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public string add_image(string curomer_name,FileUpload customer_image)
    {
        string str_curomer_name = curomer_name;
        string str_customer_image = uploadImage(customer_image, 10);
        return "ok";
    }
```

But I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltfTT.jpg.)

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

by researching the problem,
The web service use a byte datatype to save images or files in physical drive
for example the code above

use
byte[] file_upload_control
instead of
FileUpload file_upload_control